# How to add Select All option in Export Settings of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, importexport, export, massaction

I want to export one attribute of product. For this I have to select all other attributes one by one for excluding. Can anyone please tell me How can I add the Select All option to select all the option at once for exclude.

[image]

Comment: How to export all the attibute and its options via script in magento 2

Answer (score 2):

Add a "select all" button beside "Reset Filter".
We need add plugin to class Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended with getMainButtonsHtml method. As below

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended">
    <plugin name="VendorName_ModuleName::After" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended" />
</type>
```

Make a Extended.php file under VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block\Widget\Grid path. We have written selectAll javascript function.

```
    public function afterGetMainButtonsHtml(\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended $subject, $result)
{

        $result .= '<button id="" title="Select All" type="button" class="action-default scalable action-reset action-tertiary" onclick="export_filter_gridJsObject.selectAll()" data-action="grid-filter-reset" data-ui-id="widget-button-3"><span>Select All</span></button>';

    return $result;

}
```

Now we will have to extend phtml file too. For javascript function (path :magento\module-import-export\view\adminhtml\templates\export\form\filter\after.phtml)

Add this script.

```
        export_filter_gridJsObject.selectAll = function () {
    // class admin__control-checkbox is selector 
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("admin__control-checkbox");
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                inputs[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    };
```

[image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: Great that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Which file do you put the first block of code

`<config xmlns:...><type name="M..</type>`

into?

For the second bit I can see where the new php goes into extended.php.

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Ideally and in proper Magento standard way it should be -

Create a module `Vendorname_MagentoImportExportExtend`

1. Create `app/code/Vendorname/MagentoImportExportExtend/registration.php`

> ```
> <?php
> \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
>     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
>     'Vendorname_MagentoImportExportExtend',
>     __DIR__
> );
> ```

2. Create `app/code/Vendorname/MagentoImportExportExtend/composer.json`

> ```
> {
>     "name": "vendorname/magento-import-export-extend",
>     "description": "N/A",
>     "require": {
>         "php": "~7.3.0||~7.4.0",
>         "magento/framework": "103.0.*",
>         "magento/module-backend": "102.0.*",
>         "magento/module-import-export": "101.0.*"
>     },
>     "type": "magento2-module",
>     "version": "1.0.1",
>     "license": [
>         "MIT"
>     ],
>     "autoload": {
>         "files": [
>             "registration.php"
>         ],
>         "psr-4": {
>             "Vendorname\\MagentoImportExportExtend\\": ""
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Create `app/code/Vendorname/MagentoImportExportExtend/etc/module.xml`

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
>     <module name="Vendorname_MagentoImportExportExtend">
>         <sequence>
>             <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
>             <module name="Magento_ImportExport"/>
>         </sequence>
>     </module>
> </config>
> ```

4. Create `app/code/Vendorname/MagentoImportExportExtend/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
>     <event name="backend_block_widget_grid_prepare_grid_before">
>         <observer name="backend_importexport_filter_grid_add_additional_button"
>                   instance="Vendorname\MagentoImportExportExtend\Observer\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended\Button"/>
>     </event>
> </config>
> ```

5. Create  `app/code/Vendorname/MagentoImportExportExtend/Observer/Backend/Block/Widget/Grid/Extended/Button.php`

> ```
> <?php
> declare(strict_types = 1);
>
> namespace Vendorname\MagentoImportExportExtend\Observer\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
>
> use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
> use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
> use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
>
> class Button implements ObserverInterface
> {
>     /**
>      * Apply select all button
>      *
>      * @param Observer $observer
>      * @return void
>      * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
>      */
>     public function execute(Observer $observer)
>     {
>         /** @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid $grid */
>         $grid = $observer->getEvent()->getData('grid');
>         if ($grid instanceof Grid && $grid->getId() == 'export_filter_grid') {
>             $grid->setChild(
>                 'select_all_button',
>                 $grid->getLayout()->createBlock(
>                     \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button::class
>                 )->setData(
>                     [
>                         'label' => __('Select All'),
>                         'onclick' => $grid->getJsObjectName() . '.selectAll()',
>                         'class' => 'action-selectall select action-tertiary'
>                     ]
>                 )->setDataAttribute(['action' => 'grid-select-all'])
>             );
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

6. Create `app/code/Vendorname/MagentoImportExportExtend/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
>     <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended">
>         <plugin name="backend_importexport_filter_grid_additional_button"
>            sortOrder="10"
>      type="Vendorname\MagentoImportExportExtend\Plugin\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended"/>
>     </type>
> </config>
> ```

7. Create `app/code/Vendorname/MagentoImportExportExtend/Plugin/Backend/Block/Widget/Grid/Extended.php`

> ```
> <?php
> declare(strict_types = 1);
>
> namespace Vendorname\MagentoImportExportExtend\Plugin\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
>
> class Extended
> {
>     /**
>      * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended $subject
>      * @param $result
>      * @return mixed|string
>      */
>     public function afterGetMainButtonsHtml(
>         \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended $subject,
>         $result
>     ) {
>         if ($subject->getId() == 'export_filter_grid' && $subject->getFilterVisibility()) {
>             $result .= $subject->getChildHtml('select_all_button');
>         }
>
>         return $result;
>     }
> }
> ```

8. Create `app/code/Vendorname/MagentoImportExportExtend/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_export_getfilter.xml`

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
>     <container name="root" label="Root">
>         <block class="Magento\ImportExport\Block\Adminhtml\Export\Filter"
>      name="export.filter"/>
>         <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Magento_ImportExport::export/form/filter/after.phtml"
>      name="export.form.after" as="form_after"/>
>         <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template"
>                template="Vendorname_MagentoImportExportExtend::export/form/filter/after.phtml"
>                name="wcl.export.form.after" after="-" />
>     </container>
> </layout>
> ```

9. Create `app/code/Vendorname/MagentoImportExportExtend/view/adminhtml/templates/export/form/filter/after.phtml`

> ```
> <?php
> /** @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Template $block */
> /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
> ?>
>
> <?php $scriptString = <<<script
> require([
>     'mage/adminhtml/grid',
>     'mage/translate'
> ], function(grid, t){
>     if (window['export_filter_gridJsObject'] != undefined) {
>         export_filter_gridJsObject.selectAll = function () {
>             var element = document.querySelector(".action-selectall");
>             if (element.classList.contains('select')) {
>                 element.classList.remove('select');
>                 element.classList.add('deselect');
>                 var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("admin__control-checkbox");
>                 for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
>                     if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
>                         inputs[i].checked = true;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 element.firstChild.innerHTML = t('Deselect All');
>             } else if (element.classList.contains('deselect')) {
>                 element.classList.remove('deselect');
>                 element.classList.add('select');
>                 var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("admin__control-checkbox");
>                 for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
>                     if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
>                         inputs[i].checked = false;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 element.firstChild.innerHTML = t('Select All');
>             }
>         };
>     }
> });
> script;
> ?>
> <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false) ?>
> ```

It is tested with Magento 2.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

We have done coding to add, "Select All" with the Export filter.

Create `Czargroup\Exportproduct\etc\adminhtml\di.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Czargroup_Exportproduct_Plugin_Backend_Magento_Backend_Block_Widget_Grid_Extended" sortOrder="10" type="Czargroup\Exportproduct\Plugin\Backend\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And    `Czargroup\Exportproduct\etc\module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Czargroup_Exportproduct" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

And `Czargroup\Exportproduct\Plugin\Backend\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended.php`

```
<?php
namespace Czargroup\Exportproduct\Plugin\Backend\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid;
class Extended
{
    public function afterGetMainButtonsHtml(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $result .= '<button id="" title="Select All" type="button" class="action-default scalable action-reset action-tertiary" onclick="export_filter_gridJsObject.selectAll()" data-action="grid-filter-reset" data-ui-id="widget-button-3"><span>Select All</span></button>';

        return $result;
    }
}
```

And `/vendor/magento/module-import-export/view/adminhtml/templates/export/form/filter/after.phtml` Line 18

```
export_filter_gridJsObject.selectAll = function () {
            // class admin__control-checkbox is selector 
            var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("admin__control-checkbox");
            for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                    inputs[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        };
```

And `Czargroup\Exportproduct\registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Czargroup_Exportproduct',
    __DIR__
);
```

And `Czargroup\Exportproduct\composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "czargroup/module-exportproduct",
    "description": "Add Select All option in Export Settings",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [
        {
            "email": "info@mage2gen.com",
            "name": "Mage2Gen"
        },
        {
            "email": "pilukamani@gmail.com",
            "name": "Pratik Kamani"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Czargroup\\Exportproduct\\": ""
        },
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```