# Add 'Select All' option to Export screen in Magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2.2, export

In Magento admin, under **System > Export** the user can select individual attributes to be excluded from the export. I'd like to add a 'Select all' link that would select all options.

This question was 90% answered by Nadim here: [How to add Select All option in Export Settings of Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132574/how-to-add-select-all-option-in-export-settings-of-magento-2) , but it's lacking some detail for me to get the job done.

A) I assume this is created as a module - what should the module.xml look like?

B) Which file should the below XML go to?

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended">
    <plugin name="VendorName_ModuleName::After" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended" />
</type>
```

(I would have asked this as a comment to the original answer, but unfortunately my reputation is not high enough to add comments.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of you.

1. Your `module.xml` file look like this at following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Extension" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

2. you need to create `di.xml` at the following location with that code.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended">
    <plugin name="VendorName_ModuleName::After" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended" />
</type>
```